# Error : redefintion of int main : I wrote some basic code that's running fine on visual studio but not on a online IDE

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int compute(int x, int y){
    int sum = x*x + y*y ;
    return sum;
}


int main()  {
    int A, B;
    cin>>A>>B;
    cout<<compute(A, B)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Above is the code, which runs fine on Visual Studio, but isn't running on this site : https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/functions-basic/
The code is for the question mentioned in the link.
Why is this happening?
This is the error message :

```
Error!
solution.cpp:22:5: error: redefinition of 'int main()'

   24 | int main()  {

      |     ^~~~

solution.cpp:13:5: note: 'int main()' previously defined here

   15 | int main()  {

      |     ^~~~
```

Comment: Probably this online "IDE" automatically combines your code with a the main function...

Comment: They are certainly using their own main to test the function you are required to code : *"Create a function named “compute” which takes two integer arguments A and B and returns an integer denoting A2 + B2."*

Comment: It appears your code changes removed the `/*` and `*/` surrounding the `int main` part.

Comment: Given that your code has 16 lines and you are getting an **error on line 22**, it can be assumed that additional lines of code are being added to your submission and that added code contains the duplicate `main()`.

Comment: Yes I removed the comments. Thank you all, I now realize that the website uses it's own main.

Answer (score 1):

That website likely defines its own `main()` internally and uses it to test your submission. Typically, these kinds of algorithm question websites don't require you to implement the code that tests your function. Indeed, the instructions only ask you to implement a `compute` function:

> Try the following example in the editor below.
>
> Create a function named “compute” which takes two integer arguments A and B and returns an integer denoting A^2 + B^2.